# ANTLR rule for function call

Tags: parsing, antlr

I'm new on ANTLR4 and I trying to parse this input

```
X = 1 2 A(2) B (2)
```

In this input, A should be a function call while B should be a variable of name B.But i have a rule in lexer that skip the whitespace.

How can i write the parser rule for this input but keeping the rule that skip whitespace

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have much experience working with parsers but if you could use regular expressions here then you can use it to skip spaces. Let me know if that's something you can use and I'll help you with the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to define a function introducer in the lexer, where you have control over the whitespaces and then continue the function call in the parser for flexible parameter handling:

```
FUNCTION_START: ID OPEN_PAR;


function: FUNCTION_START parameters CLOSE_PAR;
```

The keypoint here is that in the lexer the whitespace rule doesn't kick in while you are in another lexer rule, hence the `FUNCTION_START` rule will only accept input of the form `identifer(` with no whitespaces inbetween. It will not match `B (`.